# I added firebase to my unity project and build failed

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

Please help!
I had attached a screenshot. Can anyone tell why build failed?
I have firebase added to my project.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a few issues, the first that comes to mind: if you are using OpenJDK - Groovy has some dependency changes and you will need to update your Gradle version.

Source: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/379